# Extending Fragment and Activity simultaneously in Android

Tags: java, android

I am having a problem using slide view in Android Studio. 
I can't make my button work and I don't know how to extend `Fragment` and `Activity` in the same class. Take a look and see if you can help me:

```
public class tab1 extends Fragment {


    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
    String imgDecodableString;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1,container,false);
        return view;


    }



class tab1f extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab1);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Button upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);

        upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                // Start the Intent
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);


            }


        });


    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
                // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
                imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

    }


}


}
```

Comment: *I don't know how to extend Fragment and Activity in the same class* - You can't extend multiple classes in Java.

Comment: The code sample in your submission should be between 3 and 8 lines of code, not 100.  Stackoverflow requires new users to post code, but posting entire programs like this makes a mockery of the intentions of that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

java doesn't support multiple inheritance. That means you can't have one child class from two parent classes.

I'm not very sure but check if Fragment class have any similar interface. You can then use it with your class extending Activity